# How to get selected row values to combo box from data gridview in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

There is problem with combo box values when I double-click on row of data grid view the values from the row passes to text boxes correctly but with combobox there is problem the value is not same in combobox as in data gridview row let me show you in picture.

[image: example picture]

**Used code**

For Textbox:

```
ar.txtcity.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

For Combobox:

```
combobox ar.txtcombo.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: You could provide little more information.

Do your combo have data already and you just need selected index when double clicked on DataGridView or do you add new item when double clicked?

If your combo is filled with data, did you set  ValueMember property?

Comment: yes retrieving data from database to combo that is okay but when  i want to update my data i double click the row of gridview and all the values in the text boxes are correct but in combo there always remains the first value from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
ar.txtcombo.SelectedIndex = ar.txtcombo.FindString(
                     this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

I think it will help :)

Comment: same result i would like to mention that values in the combo box is coming from the database. i want to update that inserted result using double click on the row of gridview and the value of that row passes to combo box but failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
int class= int.Parse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
NameOfYourComboBox.SelectedValue = class;
```

if the value is not in the database, you can use this;

```
NameOfYourComboBox.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

I have tried this many times and it has worked fine for me with WinForms